# Switching Dropdown List

Tags: php, jquery

I was making a dropdown switch. I mean when I choose an option of the first drop down the second will show specified message preset's in stead of the first.

```
**Dropdown one**
<select name="bantype">
    <option value="user">User ban</option>
    <option value="ip">IP ban</option>
    <option value="system">System ban</option>
</select></br></br>

**Dropdown two**
<select name="reason">
    <option value="Sexual harassment">Sexual harassment</option>
</select>
```

How can I make that when I select an option from the first dropdown that the option values of the second will switch?

Thank you for help

Comment: _I select an option from the first dropdown that the option values of the second will switch_. What do you mean by switch ? Please give more example..

Comment: If I select For example "userban" (dropdown one) that I get specified option values in dropdown two that doesn't show when I select another option value in Dropdown one.

Comment: How is first dropdown values related to second?

Comment: Justinas, it's not done yet. I don't understand how I can make that. It would be nice if someone can explain that. Thanks.

Comment: You have to call javascript function onchange of first dropdown...in function assign values to second dropdown based on value received.

Comment: @DeepPurpling You can achieve this with two ways 
1. Submit the form onchange of the first dropdown keeping the method get and action as the same page so you can load or show selected value of the second dropdown depending on the value from $_GET

2. You can do it with Ajax and the content and the selected value of the dropdown will be according to the value selected in first one.

Comment: [There's a number of examples here](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=chained+dropdown+jquery+php).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's called hierselect, chained or related selects.

I like this jquery plugin: http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/chained

Answer (score 0):

Call javascript function event `onchange`,

```
<select name="bantype" onchange="getoptions(this.value);">
   <option value="user">User ban</option>
   <option value="ip">IP ban</option>
   <option value="system">System ban</option>
</select><br/><br/>

<select name="reason" id="reason"></select>
```

In your function, use following

```
getoptions(val) {
    if(val == 'user') {
         var your_options = '<option value="abc">Abc</option>';
         jQuery('#reason').html(your_options);
         jQuery('#reason').show(); // if second dropdown is hidden
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

So you have predefined values for each dropdown value from first list

```
<select id="first">
   <option value='ban' data-show="#optionsOne">Ban Ban</option>
   <option value='banAll' data-show="#optionsTwo">Ban All</option>
</select>
```

And you have other (hidden) dropdown for each of your options:

```
<select id="optionsOne" class='drop'>...</select>
<select id="optionsTwo" class='drop'>...</select>
```

When `#first` changes values, show relative dropdown:

```
$('#first').change(function(){
     $('.drop').hide(); // hide all dropdowns
     id = $('option:selected', this).data('show'); // take relevant id
     $(id).show(); // show that dropdown with above id
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have a fixed option on page load, then here is one way to achieve what you want.

1. Give a relation between first `select` and the second one, like this:

> ```
> <select name="bantype">
> <option value="user">User ban</option>
> <option value="ip">IP ban</option>
> <option value="system">System ban</option>
> </select></br></br>
>
> **Dropdown two**
> <select name="reason">
> <option class="user" value="a">a</option>
> <option class="user" value="d">d</option>
> <option class="ip" value="b">b</option>
> <option class="system" value="c">c</option>
> </select>
> ```

1. Use jQuery to `show` and `hide` the option, like this

> ```
>  $("select[name='reason'] option").each(function(){
>      $(this).hide();
>  });
> $("select[name='bantype']").on("change", function(){
>     var selected = $(this).val();
>     $("select[name='reason'] option").each(function(){
>         if($(this).prop("class") != selected){
>             $(this).hide();
>         }else{
>             $(this).show();
>         }
>     });
> });
> ```

Check out this [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/c1tjgbup/)..